# automapper lost value when source contain navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

**Versions:**

```
ASP.NET Core 3.1
AutoMapper 10.0.0
EF Core 3.1.6
```

**My entities:**

```
public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // not equal to 'RoomDetail.StdSectionId', 
    // this is custom section id, ex. MyFrance
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class RoomDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }

    // not equal to 'Room.SectionId', 
    // this is origin section, ex: France
    [ForeignKey("Section")]
    public int StdSectionId { get; set; }  
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }

    public int Floor { get; set; }
}
```

**My DTO:**

```
public class RoomDetailDTO
{
    public int RoomId { get; set; }

    public int Floor { get; set; }

    public int SectionId { get; set; }

    public int StdSectionId { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following code:

```
// Mapping configuration
CreateMap<Room, RoomDetailDTO>();
CreateMap<RoomDetail, RoomDetailDTO>();

// Controller
var query = (from room in _context.Room 
            join roomDetail in _context.RoomDetail on room.Id equals roomDetail.RoomId
            where room.Id.Equals(4)
            select new { room, roomDetail }).AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable();

var roomInfo = query.First();
// roomInfo = 
// {
//     "room": {
//         "id": 4,
//         "sectionId": 15,
//         "section": null,
//         "displayName": "MyRoom"
//     },
//     "roomDetail": {
//         "id": 9,
//         "roomId": 4,
//         "room": null,
//         "stdSectionId": 1,
//         "section": null,
//         "floor": 2
//     },
// }
var dto = _mapper.Map<RoomDetailDTO>(roomInfo.room);
_mapper.Map(roomInfo.roomDetail, dto);
```

**Expected:**

```
dto = {
    "roomId": 4,
    "floor": 2,
    "sectionId": 15,
    "stdSectionId": 1,
}
```

But actual behavior:

```
dto = {
    "roomId": 4,
    "floor": 2,
    "sectionId": 0,
    "stdSectionId": 1,
}
```

The problem is that `RoomDetailDTO.SectionId` is zero after the mapping.
I tried to remove the navigation property `Section` from `RoomDetail`. It work. The `RoomDetailDTO.SectionId` is mapped.
But I sometimes need to use the navigation property, so I can't to remove it.

And I tried to ignore the navigation property, but not working :

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAllVirtual<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    var desType = typeof(TDestination);
    foreach (var property in desType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual))
    {
        expression.ForMember(property.Name, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }

    var srcType = typeof(TSource);
    foreach (var property in srcType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual))
    {
        expression.ForSourceMember(property.Name, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());
    }

    return expression;
}
```

I don't really understand what the `AutoMapper` code is doing so it's hard to debug.
If someone could explain mapper how to works for navigation property that would be great.